# Is it possible to set up multiple developers to edit the same Liferay Portal remotely?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, staging

I am new to Liferay Portal and am using 6.1 CE.  I am trying to find a way to allow multiple developers to make changes to a single Liferay Portal simultaneously.  I know that I can set up a Staging environment and allow all developers to log into the Live site and develop inside the Staging environment on that instance.  I also know that I can set up remote staging - allowing a developer to make changes on a separate staging environment (on a different Liferay instance) and then remotely publish the changes to the Live site.  I also know that multiple developers can each log in to that single remote staging environment.

What I want to know is this: Can I set up multiple Liferay instances as remote staging environments (one for each developer) that all publish to the same Live Liferay Portal Instance (separate from all staging environments)?  If so, will changes made in one remote staging environment and then published to Live be reflected in the other remote staging environments?  E.g., if a page is  changed in Staging Env. A and published to Live, will the change be seen in Staging Env. B, or would it be oblivious to the change?

I hope the question/scenario makes sense.  If further clarification is needed, please let me know so that I can add detail.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Liferay 6.1 you're able to work with [page variations](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen03-staging-and-workflow-0) - effectively branches of your content, so that you have multiple parallel versions that you can work with. This seems to come closest to what you describe, although it might not be an exact match.

You can also manually export/import pages and articles and move them around, but I have the feeling that you're looking for an automatism that works more like a distributed versioning system - I doubt you'll find that anywhere. A certain amount of manual work to disambiguate conflicts will still remain - and the interface for that is typically a bit hairy.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  As I looked into page variations they don't seem to achieve what I am looking for exactly.  Maybe that is the closest I'll get, but what I really want is to set up the "Stage" on multiple environments (Liferay instances) so that those page variations are easily ported over from the variation creator "Stage" to all other stages. Do you know if that's possible?  Thanks for the Page Variations tip.

Comment: added the second paragraph - of course, with Liferay you can implement such a system through the API, but that's probably not what you ask for

Comment: Thank you.  The second paragraph is, unfortunately, what I kind of expected, and what I was looking for.  Thank you for your help.